# How to use the field cardinality repeating in Render-CSV BW step?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, businessworks

I am building a generic CSV output module with a variable number of columns. The DataFormat in BW (5.14) lets you define repeating item and thus offers a list of items that I could use to map data to in the RenderCSV step.
But when I run this with data for >> 1 column (and loopings) only one column is generated.

Is the feature broken or do I use it wrongly?

Alternatively I defined "enough" optional columns in the data format and map each field separately - no really generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like In BW 5, when using Data Format and Parse Data to parse text, repeating elements isn’t supported. 
Please see https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-27133

> The workaround is to use Data Format resource, Parse Data and Mapper
>   activities together. First use Data Format and Parse Data to parse the
>   text into the xml where every element represents one line of the text.
>   Then use Mapper activity and tib:tokenize-allow-empty XSLT function to
>   tokenize every line and get sub-elements for each field in the lines.

The link has also attached workaround implementation

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint - but i was looking for the other way around (RenderCSV instead if ParseData. I assume the sam eproblem exists so I stick with my manual composition using a mapper step an concat-sequence-format(<array>, <separator>)

Comment: Got it. Then your workaround with manual composition using a mapper step an concat-sequence-format(<array>, <separator>) is probably the best option.